# SQL query not being executed from AJAX '$_POST' to PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, facebook

I'm retrieving user information from the facebook API and sending it via AJAX to my php file to write into the mysql database.
The reason for this is so I can generate a random voucher code to give to them, which is also being written to the database.

I'm not at all experience in this and I'm just learning along the way.

my php file:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';//$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, 
DATABASE);
include_once 'psl-config.php';//database login details

if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['id'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $uid = $_POST['id'];
    $code = generateRandomString();
    $prep_stmt="INSERT INTO memberinfo (name, email, id,code,dateadded) VALUES ('$name','$email','$uid','$code',now())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    if($stmt) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
}}
```

my javascript then runs this from the facebook button with the onlogin="checkLoginState();" function:

```
    function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            FB.api('/me', { locale: 'en_US', fields: 'name,email,id' },
                function(response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: "includes/process_fb_login.php",
                        data: response,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        cache: false,
                        success: function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }

                    });
                });
        }else{
            alert("Failed to login");
        }
    });
}
```

At the moment nothing is being written into the database and I'm not even sure how to troubleshoot to see what's being executed along the way.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: No errors at all, I'm suspecting that it may not even be running past the "isset"

Comment: the db login details appear to be after the db connection - this seems the wrong way around?! Also, you are using `mysqli` and are using prepared statements but leave your sql vulnerable by embedding the variables

Comment: Yeah, could be that, I'll check tomorrow morning, thanks! Also what would you suggest regarding SQL being vulnerable? Do you mean using something like preg_replace?

Comment: This is open to SQL injection; use a prepared statement http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of issues:

Firstly - My database id was type "Integer". Meaning the ID number I was getting from facebook was 15 characters long and the maximum value you can have is 2147483647(10 chars) (Signed) or 4294967295 (Unsigned). So I changed this to varchar.

Secondly - It seems that `if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['id']))` was stuffing me up a bit, I couldn't get it to run past that line.
In the end this is the code that worked for me.
Not sure if it's the best way to do it but, hey, it works for me.

```
$email_exists="select email from memberinfo where email ='".$_POST['email']."'";
$exe = $mysqli->prepare($email_exists);
if($exe) {
    $exe->execute();
    $exe->store_result();
    if ($exe->num_rows == 1) {
        // A user with this email address already exists
        $exe->close();
    } else {
        $prep_stmt = "INSERT INTO memberinfo (name, email,username,id,code,dateAdded) 
    VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['email']."','".$_POST['id']."','$code',now())";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($prep_stmt);
    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
}}
```

Comment: Side note: The use of prepare/execute without placeholders doesn't constitute as a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) per se. You're still leaving yourself open to SQL injection.